# Parse error while creating External Table

Tags: hive, external

I am  new to Hadoop. I am trying to create an EXTERNAL table in Hive.

The following is the query I am using:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE stocks (
exchange STRING,
symbol STRING,
ymd STRING,
price_open FLOAT,
price_high FLOAT,
price_low FLOAT,
price_close FLOAT,
volume INT,
price_adj_close FLOAT
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION 'hdfs:///data/stocks'
```

I am getting an error:

> ' ParseException cannot recognize input near 'exchange' 'STRING' ',' in column specification.

What am I missing? I tried reading the command  - I don't think I am missing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `exchange` is a keyword in hive, so you can't use `exchange` to be your column name. If you want to use it just add backticks around `exchange`

Answer (score 0):

Exchange is reserved keyword in Hive So try to use different keyword in place of that-

Create table Stocks (exchange1 String, stock_symbol String, stock_date String, stock_price_open double, stock_price_high double, stock_price_low do
uble, stock_price_close double, stock_volume double, stock_price_adj_close double) row format delimited fields terminated by ",";